# Change borderColor in React Component

Tags: reactjs

how to change color of component from clicking a button from another.
I'm trying to this by setting state, but it's not possible. And in this of component SecondAnotherBox not styles in properties.

```
var AnotherBox = React.createClass({
    boxclick: function()
    {
        //change from here
    },
    render: function()
    {
        return(
        <div onClick={this.boxclick}> anotherbox</div>)
    }
});
var SecondAnotherBox = React.createClass({//change this
    render: function()
    {
        return(
        <div> secondanotherbox</div>)
    }
});
var ComplexBox = React.createClass({
    render: function()
    {
        return(
        <div>
        <AnotherBox />
        <SecondAnotherBox />
        </div>)
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(
  <ComplexBox />,
  document.getElementById('test')
);
```

Comment: You had to pass a callback to `AnotherBox ` as props. This callback will update the state of `ComplexBox `. This state contains the border color and must be passed as prop to `SecondAnotherBox `

Comment: Can you please update your question with the relevant styles you want to apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three components

ComplexBox with AnotherBox and SecondAnotherbox.

- Keep your state in ComplexBox.
- move your boxClick function to ComplexBox
- add property onBoxClick to AnotherBox and connect onClick to { this.props.onBoxClick }
- add property to SecondAnotherBox color and use "ComplexBox.state.color" as value
- in boxClick function change "ComplexBox.state.color"

It would look something like this in code ...

```
    var AnotherBox = React.createClass({

        render: function()
        {
            return(
            <div onClick={this.props.onBoxClick}> anotherbox</div>);
        }
    });

    var SecondAnotherBox = React.createClass({//change this
        render: function()
        {
            return(
            <div style={{ borderColor: this.props.color }}> secondanotherbox</div>);
        }
    });

    var ComplexBox = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {
            return {
                color: 'blue'  
            };
          },
        boxclick: function()
        {
            //change from here
            var newColor = this.state.color == 'red'?'blue':'red'; 

            this.setState({
                color: newColor
            })
        },
        render: function()
        {
            return(
            <div>
                <AnotherBox onBoxClick={this.boxclick} />
                <SecondAnotherBox color={this.state.color} />
            </div>);
        }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(
      <ComplexBox />,
      document.getElementById('test')
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `+` CSS selector if you like. See a [pen here](https://codepen.io/DriftDesign/pen/MpVwpY)

I think this is very fragile however. Slight changes to the DOM layout will break this. You are far better off using a global state manager like redux and passing this information down to your components as props.

EDIT: You can still achieve this using only react state.
Another [pen for demo](https://codepen.io/DriftDesign/pen/QpmbxL).

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try to put a state on your container ComplexBox, like that:

```
 var AnotherBox = React.createClass({
    boxclick: function()
    {
      //change from here
    },
    render: function()
    {
      return(
        <div
          onClick={this.boxclick}
          style={ this.props.boxClicked === 1 ? color: blue }
        >
          anotherbox
        </div>
      )
    }
  });
var SecondAnotherBox = React.createClass({//change this
  render: function()
  {
    return(
      <div style={ this.props.boxClicked === 2 ? color: blue }> secondanotherbox</div>)
  }
});
var ComplexBox = React.createClass({

  constructor: function() {
    this.state: { boxClicked: 1 }
  }
  render: function()
  {
    return(
      <div>
        <AnotherBox
          boxClicked: this.state.boxClicked
        />
        <SecondAnotherBox
          boxClicked: this.state.boxClicked
        />
      </div>)
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(
  <ComplexBox />,
  document.getElementById('test')
);
```